# How can I get jquery to format propery in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: jquery, sublimetext3

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ZSQ5.png)

Hi all,
When I drag my jquery file into Sublime text editor, it displays it as regular text with no formatting, with an infinite horizontal scrool bar. I can't get it to format properly. I tried installing jquery via Preferences > Package Control, and that didn't change anything. There must be an incredibly simple fix for this that I'm not seeing. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Its like that because its minified.Google jquery beautifier. And paste your code there. It will give you proper format.

Comment: .. or obtain the unminified version

Comment: I've downloaded the unminified version and it works now! Thank you! :D